# Deleting files whose filenames match strings contained in a file

Tags: linux, grep, find

There is a text file, `del.txt`, containing a list of randomly-generated identifying strings, for example:

```
07ckv978yk0
HuinLBoZHcY
_oR7ccXiunY
```

I would like to delete any files whose filenames contain any of the identifying strings. The filenames would be in the format of `20191223_abcdef_07ckv978yk0.json`, where the matching string would certainly be found at the end of the filename, just before the file extension which may not necessarily be .json. There may also be multiple files matching each string, but never multiple strings matching to one file.

I've tried something like `find . -type f -name "*" -exec grep -Flf ~/del.txt '{}' \; -print` and while it seems to work, it takes a *very* long time (there are 2000 strings to be matched and even more filenames to check). I could make it quicker by specifying the extension but there are quite a few different file extensions and I was hoping for a smarter way of doing it.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Can a filename contain several of those strings? Can a matched string appear in the wrong spot (not exactly before the extension)?

Comment: I've added a bit about what I've tried.

The filenames cannot contain more than one of the strings. I forgot about it when I wrote this question, but the matched string **can** appear in the wrong spot, something like ```07ckv978yk0.info.json```.

Comment: What about more than one period? Your own attempt, btw, would also kill files where the matched string is in the wrong spot.

Comment: The only time there would be more than one period is in the example offered in the previous comment. I am not concerned with the matched string being in the wrong spot. As long as the string is in the filename somewhere, it should be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've written your find command, it's:

1. running `grep` once for each filename
2. grepping the **contents** of each file, not the file **name** itself.

That will be extremely slow, and not do what you actually want.

Try something more like this:

```
find . -type f | grep -Ff ~/del.txt
```

That will run grep just once, and it will grep the filenames, not the file contents.

If you want to delete matching files at the same time, rather than just generate a list of files to be deleted:

```
find . -type f -print0 | grep -z -Ff ~/del.txt | xargs -0r rm
```

This uses NUL as the separator between the filenames (which is the ONLY character that can not be in a path/filename) so is safe to use with any filename, even those containing spaces, newlines, and shell meta-characters.

---

Both version above will match the fixed strings in `del.txt` wherever they appear in the filename.  If you only want to match at specific locations within the filename, you'll have to use regular expressions rather than fixed strings.  Or perhaps use something more capable/flexible than grep to do the matching (e.g. `awk` or `perl`, both of which have no trouble handling NUL separated input - and perl also has a built-in `unlink()` function to delete files so wouldn't need `xargs`).

If you just wanted something simple like the patterns only matching before any filename "extension", a literal `.` character, then you could modify `del.txt` so that each fixed string ended in a `.`

You could do that manually be editing the file, or you could use [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution)
and `sed` to modify it on the fly.  For example:

```
find . -type f -print0 |
  grep -z -Ff <(sed -E -e 's/([^.])$/\1./' del.txt) |
  xargs -0r rm
```

The `sed` command adds a `.` to every line that doesn't already end in a `.` - note that it doesn't modify `del.txt` itself, it just modifies a stream copy, which is then used by grep's `-f` option.

Comment: When I run ```find . -type f | grep -Flf ~/del.txt```, all I get is ```(standard input)```

Comment: Ah. I should have got rid of grep's `-l` option.  it's meant to be grepping the output of `find` (a list of filenames) rather than the files themselves.  fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In `zsh`:

```
blacklist=( ${(f)"$(<del.txt)"} )
print -rC1 -- **/*(${(~j[|])blacklist}).*(D.)
```

prints them `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn. To remove them, replace `print -rC1` with `rm -f`.

Or without the temporary array:

```
print -rC1 -- **/*(${(~j[|])${(f)"$(<del.txt)"}}).*(D.)
```

- `"$(<del.txt)"` expands to the contents of the file minus the trailing newline characters like in ksh
- the `f` parameter expansion flag splits on line`f`eed characters, short for `ps[\n]`, so `$blacklist` is an array with each element being the contents of non-empty lines in `del.txt`.
- `j[|]` joins elements with `|`. With `~`, that `|` is treated as a glob operator rather than literally. So we end up with a `**/*(07ckv978yk0|HuinLBoZHcY|_oR7ccXiunY).*` glob pattern.
- `**/` any level of subdirectories.
- `D`: also include `D`otfiles (hidden files)
- `.`: restrict to *regular* files

Answer (score 0):

If there aren't thousands of files to delete:

```
rm `sed 's/^/*/;s/$/.*/' del.txt`
```

This takes each line of the file, converts it with *sed* to a glob pattern like `*idstring.*` and puts it on the command line for *rm* to remove.

If there are too many id strings in `del.txt`, the command line might be too long for the shell to accept.

To see what would be deleted first, replace *rm* with *ls*.

Note: This doesn't work with *zsh* the way I have it set up (you need an *eval*), but it works in *bash* and *sh*. It even works with filenames that have spaces and other shell metacharacters, which I admit surprised me.

If any of the files with matching id strings have already been deleted, there will be error messages. Use `rm -f` instead, or redirect `2>/dev/null`, or delete `del.txt` after the deletion command.